# AWS DataSync: Unable to connect to S3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-datasync

I am trying to sync two S3 buckets in different accounts. I have successfully configured the locations and created a task. However, when I run the task I get a `Unable to connect to S3 endpoint` error. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Unless you provide a little more detail on your configuration it's tough to help you. You should be able to find the solution at ["How to use AWS DataSync to migrate data between Amazon S3 buckets"](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/storage/how-to-use-aws-datasync-to-migrate-data-between-amazon-s3-buckets/) as it seems to describe exactly your use case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Datasync S3 -> S3 cross account, confused about destination role/account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821694/aws-datasync-s3-s3-cross-account-confused-about-destination-role-account)

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding, i have updated the question to show the image

Comment: You could have cropped the picture better ... did you look into the links I've posted?

Comment: It is possible that the s3 bucket is deleted? i had this issue when my source s3 bucket was deleted but i ran the task without knowing that.

Comment: @UtibeabasiUmanah what is your solution? I have the same problem too

Answer (score 1):

This could have been related to the datasync's IAM role's policy (datasync IAM role) not having permission to the target S3 bucket

verify your policy and trust relationship using the below documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/using-identity-based-policies.html

Also turn on cloudwatch logs (like shown in the image) and view detailed log in cloudwatch. If it is permission related, add the missing policy in the Datasync role.

[image]